# how to dump multiple levels LINQPAD

Tags: .net, linqpad

when i do a object.dump() i can get only 1 level. How do i do multiple levels. is ther any examples.

Comment: You need to be more specific... Post an example of what you're doing, and tell us what you expect and what you see. Dump normally shows multiple levels (if there *are* multiple levels of course)

Comment: You can see the screenshot in http://screencast.com/t/vxDMfMIX where  i have framed the keyvaluepair that i cannot see expanded. how do i get it done? The code i used is 
var connstr = "Server=localhost:27017";
mongo = new Mongo(connstr);
mongo.Connect();
mongo.GetDatabase("TorontoTrader").GetCollection("TradingStrategyRefresher").Dump();

Answer (score 5):

Looking at that screenshot, the simple answer is that LINQPad's default Dump depth of 5 is not enough for that object graph. You can increase it by calling Dump with a numeric argument:

```
obj.Dump(6);  // dump 6 levels deep
```

(A more subtle issue is that LINQPad has hit its graph limit in between a list node and its members and this is a bit ugly. I've fixed this for the next LINQPad build.)